# Strange behavior when setting a layout in before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I am trying to create a module to abstract some logic I use for choosing a layout for actions in a controller.

Here's what an example controller looks like:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  second_tierable only: [:new, :create]
  layout "students"
  ...
```

I have included a module in ApplicationController that defines the following class method:

```
def second_tierable(options = {})
  self.send(:before_filter, options.slice(:only, :except)) do
    self.class.layout "second_tier_page"
  end
end
```

Here's what I expect to happen:

- The layout is "second_tier_page" if the action is new or create.
- The layout is "students" otherwise

This is exactly what happens, EXCEPT after either the new or create action is run. If I visit "students/new", for example, and then visit "students/index," then the "second_tier_page" layout is rendered for index.

I am running my app in development mode. Interestingly, if I make a change to ANY file in my app and save, when I refresh "index" the correct layout renders. This leaves me to believe that something is being cached somewhere, but I am at a loss for the root problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use `render layout: 'second_tier_page'` for the respective actions?

Comment: I'd follow Koraktor's advice. I suppose the unexpected behaviour comes from class caching; in order to make this work you'd have to call the before_filter on every request and set the layout according to the current action.

Comment: In development mode, there is no class caching. That's why this behavior is so strange. I can take the approach of rendering the layout for each action, but my goal was to abstract this since I have this same behavior throughout the app, and I'd prefer not to clutter the controller with lots of render calls. The abstraction appears not to be worth it, unless there's something I'm missing :)

Comment: @Fivell no I dropped the whole idea. It was a "nice to have" but certainly not necessary to get the desired behavior!